# multiple images should be uploaded from iphone to a php server

Tags: php, iphone, http, uiimage

multiple images should be uploaded from iphone to a php server and images will be sent to php server as an http request.

something like this www.ursite.com/event_id=1234qwer&method=upload&data=!@#$%^&*&^%$#@!!....

data=!@#$%^&&^%$#@!!&&(&&$$%$@$@GFGF%$4....

it would a random value and it is packet of data[images]. We need to read this raw data using php

how can I do that??

http://pastebin.com/WAp5AV5Y

Comment: Can you show us the *real* data, please?  If it's huge, use a pastebin to contain it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WAp5AV5Y  The actual raw data. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be sending your data as a GET request, you should be sending it as a multipart POST call. There's plenty of resources about that over the web, SO included. Also [check out this page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUpload).

On the PHP side you will receive the uploaded files in the $_FILES array just as if the user uploaded the images from a HTML form so you don't need to do anything special to handle an iPhone upload.

Comment: How can i read this raw data using php? can u pls give an example?

Comment: Take the first PHP file upload tutorial that you can find. For example, [this one](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php).

Comment: this raw data is in encoded format rite?? then how can we read as a $_FILE array using php?

Comment: What do you mean by encoded format? What do you mean by raw data?

Comment: Well the data that's going to get sent to the server would be the actual JPG/PNG image(s). That data will be automatically written to disk by PHP in the temporary directory. You are going to have to then copy the temporary files (you will get access to them by looking into the $_FILES array) to your place of choosing. Look into the **PHP - File Upload: move_uploaded_file Function** section of the tutorial I gave you.

Comment: sorryy.....for the very late reply...   I used this solution in my project  and submitted  and it was a success. thank u...

Answer (score 0):

I have some good news, and I have some bad news.

The good news is that the image data is just a JPEG, so GD's [`imagecreatefromstring`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) will do the job nicely to ensure that the data is a valid image.

The bad news is twofold:

1. The data has come in without the benefit of URL-encoding, so it is surely corrupt.
2. GET method requests have a relatively small available data size.

You will need to have the data submitted as a POST, properly encoded.

Comment: thank u..  I hope it would serve the purpose. Thank u so much